# Can't connect to AWS Network Load Balancer with Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer, aws-ecs

I've created a Network Load Balancer for use with ECS Fargate.  When I try to connect to the load balancer (using either the ELB domain name or it's IP addresses) it won't connect.  I don't even see the connection in the flow logs.  The machine I'm using to connect to the LB can reach the instances fine, but when I try to hit it through the load balancer I don't get a TCP connection.  The security group on the Fargate containers allows anything from anywhere.  The load balancer shows the instances health checks as "Healthy" but I still can't get to them.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the ECS task definition to use awsvpc network mode instead of bridge mode resolved this issue for us.

Comment: You can't change vpc while launching on Fargate mode

Comment: This answer is irrelevant, awsvpc is the only network type acceptable on Fargate. You can't even change it.